# mongo console: how to print an element's internal type

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, pymongo

With [$type](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) and $match, I can find iteratively discover what types Mongo thinks my data has. With [$not](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/), I can get the results even faster sometimes.

Is there a way to [project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) the type of an element in a document directly? (I presume I could get it with pymongo, but I haven't looked there yet.)
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could sort of do this with mapReduce. I can demonstrate for simplicity but complex structures would take more implementation to actually work through recursively.

So given a document.

```js
db.team.find()
{
    "_id" : 50,
    "team_name" : "bulls",
    "players" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 100,
                    "player_name" : "Jokim"
            }
    ],
    "sub" : {
            "opt" : 1
    },
    "long" : NumberLong(123),
    "int" : 1,
    "bool" : false,
    "date" : ISODate("2014-06-03T01:42:01.016Z"),
    "unset" : null,
    "id" : ObjectId("538d36ccb88d0a9b6195ca66")
}
```

You could run this "basic" mapper:

```js
db.team.mapReduce(
    function () {

        var obj = {};

        for ( var k in this ) {
            var type = ( this[k] != null ) 
                ? this[k].constructor.toString() : null;
            var match = null;
            if (type != null)
                match = type.match(/^function\s(\w+)/);

            obj[k] = ( match != null ) ? match[1]
                : ( type != null ) ? 'Object' : null;

        }

        emit( this._id, obj );

    },
    function(){},
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

Which gives you output like this:

```js
"results" : [
    {
        "_id" : 50,
        "value" : {
            "_id" : "Number",
            "team_name" : "String",
            "players" : "Array",
            "sub" : "Object",
            "long" : "NumberLong",
            "int" : "Number",
            "bool" : "Boolean",
            "date" : "Date",
            "unset" : null,
            "id" : "ObjectId"
        }
    }
],
```

You can take that as far as you need, going recursively into "Array" or "Object" ( sub-document ) types. But that is one way to output a "type" for the given field/property.

Comment: Wow how neat. That's exactly what I want but I have trouble on two parts. 1.When I type  JS xx.constructor.toString(); into the console I don't see the nice answer? ; 2.I am getting OOM which I think I can fix with another map/reduce step. "map reduce failed:{
 "errmsg" : "exception: too much data for in memory map/reduce",
 "code" : 13604,
 "ok" : 0"

Comment: @AnneTheAgile Seems like you are running over the entire collection. You can output to another collection, or otherwise tweak the mapper and the reducer to gather "statistics" as it were over your collection for what fields and "types" exist. This is really just proof of concept saying that you can use JavaScript to inspect the BSON types in this way. Your end solution would take much more work.

Comment: @AnneTheAgile Having a few minutes I've cleaned up the "type" names for you. Simple regex really.

Comment: thank you so much for educating me on several respects! I didn't know/grok before that the second match output would remove any specified 'constants' in the string. That is so helpful. Notes for self; 1.Example Regex: IN= > match = "function Array() { [native code] }".match(/^function\s(\w+)/); OUT= [ "function Array", "Array" ]  ; 2.Neil's original loop was simply: obj[k] = this[k].constructor.toString();

Comment: 3.MongoDB's RAM limit for map-reduce can be easily fixed by outputting to a collection, http://blog.evilmonkeylabs.com/2011/01/27/MongoDB-1_8-MapReduce/ http://blog.mongodb.org/post/3903149313/mongodb-1-8-released